# How to edit data array to checkbox with javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, checkbox

Table Form HTML

```
 <table id="example3" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
      <tr>
         <th></th>
         <th>Nama</th>
         <th>Unit</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
 </table>
```

Javascript to headle select row

```
$('#frm-example').on('submit', function(e){ //on submit
    var form = this;
    var rows_selected = table3.column(0).checkboxes.selected();

        // Iterate over all selected checkboxes
        $.each(rows_selected, function(index, rowId){
           // Create a hidden element 
           $(form).append(
              $('<input>')
              .attr('type', 'hidden')
              .attr('name', 'id[]')
              .val(rowId)
           );
       });
```

My database

```
+-----------+--------------+---------------+-----------+-------------+-----------+------------------------------+---------------------+
| id_survey | judul_survey | status_survey | id_target | id_kategori | responden | detail_target                | tgl_survey          |
+-----------+--------------+---------------+-----------+-------------+-----------+------------------------------+---------------------+
|       130 | tes          | terbit        |         3 |           2 |         2 | 198411162009101002,H76215021 | 2017-12-19 15:08:35 |
+-----------+--------------+---------------+-----------+-------------+-----------+------------------------------+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.07 sec)
```

Data checkbox in field `detail_kategori`, how i can put this into form checkbox for update?

Ok, i get code checkbox from here https://jsfiddle.net/gyrocode/07Lrpqm7/
I want modify the code to edit

Comment: no idea what you ae asking

Comment: Ok, i get code checkbox from here https://jsfiddle.net/gyrocode/07Lrpqm7/ . I want modify the code to edit

Comment: You want to edit the selected row's values...?

Comment: yes sir, i want edit selected row

Comment: There are no checkboxes in the HTML you show.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this with jQuery:

```
$("#frm-example").submit(function() {
    var form = $(this);
    $("#table3 :checkbox:checked").each(function() {
        form.append($("<input>", {
            type: "hidden",
            name: "id[]",
            value: this.id
        }));
    });
});
```